# What is a correct answer/behavior in response to such questions?

Tags: discussion

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367442/how-to-edit-apk-file-using-android-studio-3-0-1#50367442) where OP is asking "how to decompile an APK and get access to its source code", as a resume. Under the question I made my point arguing that such questions shouldn't be answered nor should any material/tools be provided as it could lead to some immoral behaviors.

Another user answered, and I downvoted, explaining why I did in the comments
(that is just for the background, I believe this is all about personal opinion anyway, but I thought it was more of a comment than an answer). He then answered telling me that his answer was the only good one.

Here is his original answer to the question:

> You don't just edit APK files. You could decompile it, but that's likely illegal, because if you had permission to do that, you'd probably have access to the source code. Which you obviously don't.

My point is the following, and that's also what I answered him in the comment section:

> *Such questions shouldn't be answered at all and just downvoted*

Was I wrong? Why?

I truly believe stealing some peoples' work using probably illegal tools shouldn't be helped.